# change the serial number of letters by year

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, autonumber

how to change the serial number of letters by year, I got the formula in microsoft excel but how to use the formula in googlesheet with the array method formula to those who understand please guide me, just an illustration of the formula I use in excel I include in the following picture

[excel formula into arrayformula on googlesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkz9V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in C2:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="";;COUNTIFS(B2:B; B2:B; ROW(B2:B); "<="&ROW(B2:B))
```

[image]

Comment: i try this formula on googlesheet it say error .. anyway thanks

Comment: @autoform answer updated, try now

Answer (score 0):

Your locale may require the use of semicolons instead of comma's. Using player0's formula, try

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="";;COUNTIFS(B2:B; B2:B; ROW(B2:B); "<="&ROW(B2:B))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: in googlesheet its still doesnt work

Comment: https://ibb.co/rmPN6xt

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet so we can have a closer look?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zBnGttg_5HS9Dkosrw_U8fkJkfkW-c9rjxrsCjcubcE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing. The formula seems to be working correctly.